# How to use graphql useStaticQuery in a react class component

Tags: reactjs, graphql

How do I use react's useStaticQuery in a react class component class. I have seen many examples using react functional components, but I am interested in knowing how it is done in a class component because i prefer writing class components.

I would like to convert something like this into a react component impletented as class.

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query SiteTitleQuery {
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  return (
    <>
      <Header siteTitle={data.site.siteMetadata.title}/>
      <Home/>
      <AboutMe/>

    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hooks can't be used in class components. Use `StaticQuery` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the StaticQuery component and wrap it around the parts you want to render.

There is explicit documentation for this, check out: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-query/

In your case it could look something like this:

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const query = graphql`
    query SiteTitleQuery {
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  `;

  return (
    <StaticQuery query={query}>
      {({ loading, error, data }) => {
        <>
          <Header siteTitle={data.site.siteMetadata.title} />
          <Home />
          <AboutMe />
        </>;
      }}
    </StaticQuery>
  );
};
```